# How to get Pysqlcipher to detect openssl during installation

Tags: python-2.7, openssl, sqlcipher, pysqlcipher

I am trying to Install pysqlcipher to enable me use sqlcipher function in python. While installing pysqlcipher I got an error saying

> Fatal error: OpenSSL could not be detected!

I then tried to install openssl

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install pyopenssl
```

I got a successful message

> Successfully installed cffi-1.6.0 cryptography-1.3.2 enum34-1.1.6 idna-2.1 ipadd
>   ress-1.0.16 pyasn1-0.1.9 pycparser-2.14 pyopenssl-16.0.0 six-1.10.0

I then tried reinstalling pysqlcipher

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install pysqlcipher
```

The same error occurred in the process of installation.

> Fatal error: OpenSSL could not be detected!

How do I get it to detect openssl?

Pls note that I'm installing it on Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

1)Installed a prebuilt OpenSSL binary (Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.2d or later) from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

2) Confirm that the OPENSSL_CONF environment variable is set properly in environment variables. See http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm